# Node Express routes get request not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a button that links to

```
    <a href="/data_entry?Display=A&ts=<%=dateStamp%><%=locTimeStamp%>">A</a>
```

My route,

```
router.get('/data_entry/:Display/:ts', function(req,res){
console.log('get display');
 });
```

Is not being called on click. The link is being passed in the url but the page stays on the current page.

Comment: You specified a path that should be used as `/data_entry/something/somethingelse` and tried to use is with `/data_entry?foo=something&bar=somethingelse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Display and ts is passed as variables to the request object (req) so in order to access the values the from the url they will be stores in req.query

```
router.get('/data_entry', function(req, res){
    // req.query will store the display and ts values
    console.log(req.query.Display);
}
```

With these changes your code will function as expected

Answer (score 0):

In order to utilize that route, you need to call it like this

```
curl -X GET "http://localhost:3000/data_entry/A/<%=dateStamp%><%=locTimeStamp%>"
```

Be sure to also properly encode the URI. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI

If you want to use query parameters instead of named parameters, you would define your route differently and then utilize the query parameters. See: http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query

It would look like this:

```
app.get('/data_entry', function (req,res){
    console.log('get display', req.query);
});
```